# cp without options

Tags: debian, cp, file-copy

sorry for my English...

I normality copy a file without options,

```
cp origin destination
```

**but sometime I to show**

```
cp -u origin destination
```

In **man cp** give options as an obligation.
My question can please anyone explains the difference between deploy `-u` and not used it, I **muss** to use an option when I'll an ordinary copy from `A`to `B`?

Thanks

Comment: `man cp` documents all the available options.  What's wrong with its description of `-u`?

Comment: I will know the difference between using `-u` or not, when I'll copy a file and i should to used it

Comment: __a)__ no options are mandatory to `cp`; you're probably misinterpreting the manpage synopsis -- anything inside square braces `[...]` is optional. __b)__ in my opinion, you should NEVER use `-u` because it's not portable and it's error prone.

Comment: very thanks for your answer!, now I know that inside square braces `[...]` ONLY optional is...

Comment: I don't know because there are people the give `-1` like chocolate, when they KNOW, er/she later comes here the problem for a new question to ask...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cp -u` will only update the destination, if it does not exist or the source is newer that the destination.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but you,  what advice for file copy, use `-u` or not...

Comment: That's ultimately up to you and what it is that you want to accomplish. If you are just copying files from A to B, the `-u` option is not necessary.

Comment: very Thanks!, now is me more klar geworden..

Comment: `gcp` implements a `-u` option, `cp` does not. So using `-u` makes the command non-portable.

Answer (score 1):

There are no *required* options for the `cp` utility.  If the manual lists options within square brackets  in the synopsis (like `[OPTIONS]` in the GNU `cp` manual, or `[-afipv]` in the OpenBSD `cp` manual), then they are *optional*.

The `-u` (`--update`) option is a non-standard option that GNU `cp` implements. If you choose to use this option with GNU `cp`, a copy will only be made if the source file is newer than the target file, or if the target file is missing. Without the `-u` option, a copy of the source file will *always* be attempted.